# Best practices to prevent SSIS Errors based on Case

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I'm working with a pretty large SSIS based system and one of the issues that we run into every now and then is that a user will input data that will not be upper case, and then have issues with joins. We try to create numeric keys, but as we can't always control the data at the source, we still run into issues when we join on non-numeric keys.
I'm wondering what the best way is to prevent this issue? Is there a way to make SSIS case insensitive? Or a collation that will set all the SQL Server output to upper?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SSIS. The *column's* collation was set to a case-*sensitive* collation. Common practice is to use case-*insensitive* collations. You can specify a different collation  for the join but that will prevent the use of indexes that cover this field. Why are you joining on a *text* field anyway?

Comment: Where are you experiencing this problem, with the lookup component in SSIS or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have several possible solutions. The first and best one is to fix the underlying database so that it does not accept lowercase letters but setting the same collation on that field as is used on the field it is joining to. Now this might affect the application and the users will get more errors because they will no longer be able to type in lowercase, so you would need to explain that to them what the change will entail and why it is necessary. Or look at the destination, does it really need to be in uppercase? Or they could add a trigger to uppercase the field, so that it is not transparent to the application or the user that the data was changed and then they will not receive the errors. That would slow inserts down a tiny bit but likely not enough to notice unless all the data comes from a very large import.

Unfortunately, you may not have the rights to change the database and the concerns of those people will override your suggestion to do so. In  this case, you adjust the SSIS package in one of several ways to automatically convert to uppercase.

If you are using a query as your datasource (or in a lookup), then add UPPER(fieldname) instead of fieldname to the join. This may slow things down some (which is why the first solution is the preferred one.) Whether it will slow things down unacceptably is something you can only find out after you try it.

If you are doing a merge join, prior to the merge, add a data conversion task before the merge join and convert the field to uppercase. This too may cause some slowness.

Comment: I don't really see any of those solutions working for me. The client data comes in compressed form from some big clients who we have contracts with that even defines the data that we receive. We have to handle it ourselves.
As for doing an Upper, I already do that occasionally when I catch an error, however since we have many SSIS's (over a thousand), I'd like an across the board solution.
Hence, I'm wondering how other people with large systems handle the issue of case sensitivity.